# PostgreSQL - Substring to nth occurence of character

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run a query that returns the substring of a value up to the nth occurence of a particular character.

For example:

This is the value `abc|123|xyz098|password|xxxxx` and I'd like to get `abc|123|xyz098` So everything up to the third '|'. The number of characters between the delimiters changes, so I can't use a fixed index.

My thinking is to use SUBSTRING() with POSITION(). But I'm not having any success using it it to get to the nth occurence. Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

For a string result, this:

```
select split_part('abc|123|xyz098|password|xxxxx', split_part('abc|123|xyz098|password|xxxxx','|',4),1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_matches`:

```
select regexp_matches('abc|123|xyz098|password|xxxxx', '\w+\|\w+\|\w+(?=\|)')
```